# Get query string from toolbar searchview in same activity?

Tags: java, android, search, android-toolbar

I have to get search view query text in same activity without the help of listener.so what i had done so far.

***menu.xml***

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/search"
              android:title="@string/search_title"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
              android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
              android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    </menu>
```

***Manifest***

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivty" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

***searchable.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="Hint"
    android:label="Label"></searchable>
```

And in ***MainActivty*** overrided as below

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          // Do work using string
        }
    }
```

Still am unable to get the search query after the user press search key. What am doing wrong.help me if any one knows.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was having the same problem this es my menu.xml

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

I changed:

> android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
>   android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"

with:

> app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
>   app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"

The problem was that I was using AppcompatActivity and needs support v7 SearchView.

Hope this helps.